# Read XML file and display on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

please see XML file below which I am trying to display on a web page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Quotation>
 <QuotationLines>
    <Line>
       <ItemID>Item ID 1</ItemID>
       <Description>
           <TextLine ID="1">Text Line 1 Item ID 1</TextLine>
           <TextLine ID="2">Text Line 2 Item ID 1</TextLine>
           <TextLine ID="3">Text Line 3 Item ID 1</TextLine>
       </Description>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <ItemID>Item ID 2</ItemID>
        <Description>
            <TextLine ID="1">Text Line 1 Item ID 2</TextLine>
            <TextLine ID="2">Text Line 2 Item ID 2</TextLine>
        </Description>
    </Line>
  </QuotationLines>
 </Quotation>
```

I want it to show as follows as I need to identify each entry to eventually save into a database:

Item ID 1
Text Line 1 Item ID 1
Text Line 2 Item ID 1
Text Line 3 Item ID 1
Item ID  2
Text Line 1 Item ID 2
Text Line 1 Item ID 2

I have worked out how to show the itemid but cannot show just the relevant textlines to that item id.

My code is currently as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>

<script runat="server" Language="VB">  

Sub page_load()  

Dim objxml As New XmlDocument()
objxml.load (Server.MapPath("test1.xml"))
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = objxml.SelectNodes("/Quotation/QuotationLines/Line")
For Each node As XmlNode In nodeList
response.Write(node("ItemID").InnerText &"<br>")
Next

end sub

    </script>
```

Ive spent 2 days so far trying to get this to work so any help would be greatly received. I am not that knowledgeable with asp.net as I still use classic asp.

Many Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

you just need a second loop:

```
For Each node As XmlNode In nodeList
    Response.Write(node("ItemID").InnerText & "<br>")
    For Each nodeDesc As XmlNode In node("Description").ChildNodes
        Response.Write(nodeDesc.InnerText & "<br />")
    Next
Next
```